# A question about Marcinkiewicz

Tags: real-analysis, integration

let $F$ be a closed subset in bounded open interval (a,b)

Let $\delta \left( t\right) =\delta \left( t,F\right) = \inf \left\{ \left| t-s\right| :s\in F\right\}  $

Assume $b-a <1$

Show the function $ M_{0}\left( x\right)=\int _{a}^{b}\dfrac {dy} {\left( \log \dfrac {1} {\delta \left( y\right) }\right) \cdot \left| x-y\right| }$ is finite a.e in $F$

In this exercise , I use Tonelli's theorem

$\int _{F}M_{0}\left( x\right) dx$

= $\int _{F}\int _{a}^{b}\dfrac {dy} {\left( \log \dfrac {1} {\delta \left( y\right) }\right) \cdot \left| x-y\right| }dx$

=$\int _{a}^{b}\dfrac {1} {\log \left( \dfrac {1} {\delta \left( y\right) }\right) }\int _{F}\dfrac {1} {\left| x-y\right| }dxdy$

But I have no idea about next step , can you give some hint

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of integrating over $F$, integrate over $\{ \rho(x,y)\ge \delta(y)\}$.

Since $\delta(y)=\inf_{x\in F} \rho(x,y)$, we have, for all $x\in F$, $\rho(x,y)\ge \delta(y)$.  Hence, $F\subset \{ \rho(x,y)\ge \delta(y)\}$.